# can i setup a wamp server with a db on my pc, to continuously update my android app's database?

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server

Hey guys i have a basic question,

I want to know if i can setup a wamp server on my pc with a database, for that when i update something on the database on my pc, it automatically updates the database on my android app via internet, and if it is possible

im planning to put the app on the googlePlayStore, and i want to know if the users who download the app will be able to update the database of the app also thru my server.

im making an app with a db of contacts, mostly taxi services and i want to be able to update the contacts of the db thru an online server, in wich if i change a contact the user will click on the UPDATE_CONTACTS button, and i want the app to automattically check if the server is online, and if it is, UPDATE the db's on the app.

but i want the server to be on my pc, can i do it thru a Wamp_Server app, or do i need to install Windows_Server?

Thanks in Advance for all Answers!

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use a WAMP server, along with [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to accomplish this. Create an account and add the API to your server side logic.  Once that is complete, implement GCM in your app.

Check out [how to implement a GCM client in Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) for information on how to do this.

You'll be able to use push notifications from the cloud to send data (retrieved from your server application) to your app via GCM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a better solution:

1. Create a JSON file;
2. Store this JSON on the cloud;
3. Read this JSON every time your app starts.

So, your app's users always will get those contacts up to date, without any efforts.

Comment: Ola muito obrigado filipe, eu nunca conheci assim alguem que sabe muito sobre android e com quem eu possa conversar. Admiro muito suas habilidades , e queria saber se vc esta em mais alguma outra rede social onde a gente possa conversar diretamente online?

Comment: Obrigado pelas palavras @RenasDIVilhenaAlbertoManuel! Estou sim em uma rede social. Recentemente criei um perfil no [Google+](https://plus.google.com/108698774009986410607). Lá podemos conversar pelo Hangouts. Toda nova amizade é sempre bem vinda! Abraços!